# ASUS N56VM-AB71 laptop suddenly shuts down on battery

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery, shutdown, asus-laptop

***Caveat**: I know an ASUS N56VM-AB71 is a 10 year old laptop, and it was only mid-range in the first place, but aside from this issue it works remarkably well and I can still even play games on it (no FPS, but that's not my genre anyhow) I'd like to continue to use it rather than replacing it.*

---

Laptop will shutdown on battery without warning. Does not hibernate, just dead.

1. I looked through logs and events, all I'm finding is one event
   "The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly."
   Event 41, kernel-power
2. Ordered a new battery. The battery now lasts longer, but it's still happening. This leads me to believe that the battery is not the primary issue. Not OEM but it's supposedly the correct size and voltage.

No idea how long this has been going on, I rarely use this machine anymore as I'm usually using my phone.

I'm at a loss here.

Comment: If you have it plugged in, does it run none stop?

Comment: It seems the battery is dead. See if you can replace it.  Not likely.  See if it run AC only.  If so leave it plugged in all time

Comment: I'm not sure that it's worthwhile repairing this laptop.

Comment: it runs nonstop while plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

Replacement batteries are shown for ~US$20 to $25 on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=ASUS%20N56VM-AB71%20battery&crid=38PAV77A6W06E&sprefix=asus%20n56vm-ab71%20battery%2Caps%2C82&ref=nb_sb_noss), for example. The battery simply detaches from outside as shown [in the user manual](https://www.manua.ls/asus/n56vm/manual?p=11). If you like the machine, repair is trivial... or just keep it powered on AC-adapter only.